# Obtener el dia de semana segun una fecha en javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo el siguiente codigo de una función, necesito obtener el dia de la semana a partir de un dia que se envia a la funcion, asi la tengo:

```js
    diaSemana : function(d){
      var fecha = new Date();
      var dias = ["L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S", "D"];

      var mes = fecha.getMonth()+1; //obteniendo mes
      var dia = d;
      var ano = fecha.getFullYear(); //obteniendo año
      if(dia<10)
          dia='0'+dia; //agrega cero si el menor de 10
      if(mes<10)
          mes='0'+mes; //agrega cero si el menor de 10
      var fec = (dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano);

      return dias[fec.valueAsDate.getDay()];
    }
```

Quiero mostrar junto al numero de dia, el nombre del dia de la semana, para ello le envío a la función el día.

Soy novato en JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te faltan algunas cosas, recuerda que la semana empieza el dia Domingo.  Tambien recuerda que las fechas en ingles empiezan con el mes.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```js
diaSemana = function(d){
      var fecha = new Date();
      var dias = ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"];

      var mes = fecha.getMonth()+1; //obteniendo mes
      var dia = d;
      var ano = fecha.getFullYear(); //obteniendo año
      if(dia<10)
          dia='0'+dia; //agrega cero si el menor de 10
      if(mes<10)
          mes='0'+mes //agrega cero si el menor de 10
      var fec = mes+"/"+dia+"/"+ano;
      var day = new Date(fec).getDay();
     
      return dias[day];
    }
    
    console.log(diaSemana(25));
```